# How fix/ignore this console error "TS2307: Cannot find module '@components/common/ButtonBlock' or its corresponding type declarations."

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The project runs fine, but there are a lot of errors in the console VS Code. How to get rid of them? I understand that this is swearing TS
Like this:[image]

and error in brouser:
[image]

Comment: Have you defined the paths in your tsconfig.json? 
`"paths": {
      "@components": [
        "./components/*"
      ]
    },`

Comment: Yes, 
```"baseUrl": "/",
    "paths": {
      "@components": ["./src/app/components/"],
      "@static": ["./src/app/static/"],
      "@type": ["./src/app/types/"],
      "@routes": ["./src/app/routes"],
     },```

Comment: add a "*" at the end of every path you defined.
So `./src/app/components/` becomes `./src/app/components/*`

Comment: I added, but the error persists
```"paths": {
      "@components": ["./src/app/components/*"],
      "@static": ["./src/app/static/*"],
      "@type": ["./src/app/types/*"],
      "@routes": ["./src/app/routes/*"],
     },```

Answer (score 0):

This variant  help me:

```
 "paths": {
  "@components/*": ["./src/app/components/*"],
  "@static/*": ["./src/app/static/*"],
  "@type/*": ["./src/app/types/*"],
  "@routes/*": ["./src/app/routes/*"],
 },
```